# XHTML empty tags not treated as empty tags by any browser

Tags: html, xml, xhtml

So I've tried this XHTML 1.1 code (validated at validator.w3.org) in Chrome 6, IE 8, and Firefox 3.5. The `<p>` following the `<a/>` gets hyperlinked, and the `<p>` following the `<div/>` turns red:

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.1//EN" 
    "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml11/DTD/xhtml11.dtd">
<html 
    xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
    <head>
        <title>test</title>
    </head>
    <body>
        <p><a href="http://www.yahoo.com"/></p>
        <p>
            this should not be hyperlinked
        </p>
        <div style="background:red"/>
        <p>this should not be red</p>
    </body>
</html>
```

This is really bad news for anyone trying to deal with documents using XML parsers/generators.

I might be able to just convert all `</>` tags to `<></>`, but that would mean that things like `<br/>` become `<br></br>` -- which is just weird, albeit valid.

Thoughts?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you serve your document with an XML content-type (such as `application/xhtml+xml`) then you shouldn't have this problem.

It sounds like you are serving your document as `text/html` (although [this isn't blessed by the text/html specification](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc2854), which only goes up to XHTML 1.0) in which case you need to follow [the HTML compatibility guidelines](http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml-media-types/#compatGuidelines) as you are telling browsers (and other user agents) that it is HTML rather than XHTML.

> I might be able to just convert all `</>` tags to `<></>`, but that would mean that things like `<br/>` become `<br></br>` -- which is just weird, albeit valid.

… and wrong. Some browsers will treat that as `<br><br>`. [Elements defined as EMPTY should use self-closing syntax](http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml-media-types/#C_2), [everything else should have explicit start and end tags](http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml-media-types/#C_3).

Sadly, the simple option of using the correct content-type just introduces a different problem…

[image: Internet Explorer won't open XHTML documents]

… although I believe this will be resolved when IE8 and lower lose significant market share as IE9 introduces support for XHTML.

Comment: Blahhh well that'll just take forever to happen. I guess I'll have to just convert all the non-empty elements to use the `<></>` syntax. Do you happen to know if that list on that spec is exhaustive?

Comment: Furthermore, to quote Ian Hickson, "There is no spec that allows sending XHTML 1.1 as text/html". Unfortunately this makes it practically unusable for regular web pages, because of the ineptitude of Internet Explorer.

Comment: http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/index/elements.html has an exhaustive list, look for the E column.